# How to catch WCF service activation exception?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a Web application project with WCF service.

When I run my web project under Visual Studio 2010 debugger with ASP Development server, using `Debug->Options->Break`, when `CLR exception thrown` checked and `Enable Just my code` unchecked, I can catch `ServiceActivationException` with details explanation when my WCF service didn't started, also this exception is logged with WCF tracing.

However I have not found a way to catch this exception in code. How to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

If by "code" you mean just trapping the exception for logging, then try to see if [implementing IErrorHandler](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler.aspx) will work for you. Another option might be a [custom service host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx) but if that doesn't do it, then you're pretty much out of luck trapping it outside of Visual Studio debugger. That exception occurs within the WCF framework when your service instance is being initialized. It would impossible for your code to trap it because it happens before your service code is running.

Comment: It is very unusual that such an important exception doesn't make it way to unhandled exception event handlers, and is silently handled somewhere inside.

Comment: It's all about where in the exception occurs in the WCF initialization sequence. If the IErrorHandler implementation doesn't catch it then it happens before any custom extension are loaded. Have you tried the custom ServiceHost option?